# How do I sum the number of order quantities for each part number from the current date to the current date - lead time?

Tags: sql, partitioning, snowflake-schema

I am trying to write a query to sum the amount of orders for each part number between two dates (order date and lookback date (order date - lead time)).

For example,

| Part Num | Order Date | Lookback Date | Lead Time | Order Qty | Total Orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01-20-2023 | 01-10-2023 | 10 | 2 | 3 |
| A | 01-15-2023 | 01-05-2023 | 10 | 1 | 1 |

I essentially am looking to calculate the "Total Orders" column....

This is the query I currently have and I keep getting an error for using "Lead Time" after the between function.

```
 select 
    "Part Number",
    "Snapshot Date",
    sum("Lead Time"),
    sum("Order Qty") over (partition by "Part Number" order by 
    "Snapshot Date" desc rows between "Lead Time" preceding and current 
    row) as "Total Demand"
  from table1
```

My source data is structured as :

| Snapshot Date | Part Number | Lead Time | Order Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2022 | A | 15 | 0 |
| 01-01-2022 | B | 10 | 1 |
| 01-02-2022 | A | 15 | 1 |
| 01-02-2022 | B | 10 | 0 |
| 01-03-2022 | A | 15 | 5 |
| 01-03-2022 | B | 10 | 3 |

Comment: I don't understand the question. I think: for each `(p, t)` where `p` is a part number and `t` is a lead time you want to get the total order quantity for `p` where the lead time is less than or equal to `t`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough please see edits above, looking to total order quantity for all of the orders in between the current order date and order date - lead time

Comment: Please add example source data and matching desired results for that data; [mre] ***and*** [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: Does lead time really have the text 'days' in it? Meaning that the number 10 is also actually text?

Comment: Does your source data have exactly one row per day? No gaps? No extras?

Comment: I still don't understand the question -- and I'm not convinced that you do either! For each pair of values `([Part Num], [Order Date])` you want to get the `SUM([Order Qty])` for, erm...

Comment: @MatBailie the lead time does not have text in it so I've removed from the example, it is a numerical value. My source data has every part number listed on every day with the sum of the order quantity on that day.

Comment: Please read the rest of [mre] and [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952) (the question should have both source data and desired results, etc.

Comment: @MatBailie I added the structure of the source data and the first table shows the desired results

Comment: Your results have 2 rows, your source has 6 row, but your query has no aggregation. Your results only have data for Part A, but your source data also has data for Part B. Your query columns and result columns don't match. I also can't get my head around how to derive your results from your source. Please, please actually read the whole of [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you are trying to do with the windowed function. Unfortunately you can't specify a dynamic range of rows for each window to look at. Also the ROWS specifies a number of rows and you want a number of days (relative to your Order/Snapshot date (Seems these mean the same thing. I have used SnapshotDate from here on out)).

The trick here is to calculate the LookbackDate, and then match all the relevant SnapshotDates that fall within a LookbackDate and a SnapshotDate. Then you can aggregate to get the total. So in essence a 'self join' is required.

My below solution is in T-SQL. But everything except the temp table syntax should work in Snowflake.

```
--Create some data to work with
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #InputData;
CREATE TABLE #InputData(SnapshotDate DATE NOT NULL
                    , PartNum CHAR(1) NOT NULL
                    , LeadTime BIGINT NOT NULL
                    , OrderQty BIGINT NOT NULL
                    )
INSERT INTO #InputData(SnapshotDate
                    , PartNum
                    , LeadTime
                    , OrderQty
                    )
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, X.SnapshotDate, 105)
    , X.PartNum
    , X.LeadTime
    , X.OrderQty
FROM (VALUES
            ('01-01-2022', 'A', 15, 0)
            , ('01-01-2022', 'B', 10, 1)
            , ('01-02-2022', 'A', 15, 1)
            , ('01-02-2022', 'B', 10, 0)
            , ('01-03-2022', 'A', 15, 5)
            , ('01-03-2022', 'B', 10, 3)
            
    ) X(SnapshotDate
        , PartNum
        , LeadTime
        , OrderQty
        );

    
/*
IMPORTANT ASSUMPTION: The combination of SnapshotDate and PartNum is unique.
*/      

--4. Finally do a 1 to 1 Join back onto your orginal dataset, to include the total and the lookback date.
SELECT inp.PartNum
    , inp.SnapshotDate
    , subq2.LookbackDate
    , inp.LeadTime
    , inp.OrderQty
    , subq2.OrderQtyInLastLeadManyDays
FROM #InputData inp
INNER JOIN (
    --3. Sum the order quantity for each snapshot date, lookback date and part num.
    SELECT subq.SnapshotDate
        , subq.LookbackDate
        , subq.PartNum
        , SUM(inp.OrderQty) AS OrderQtyInLastLeadManyDays
    FROM #InputData inp
    INNER JOIN(
        --1. lets create the lookback date from the SnapshotDate and the LeadTime
        SELECT SnapshotDate
            , DATEADD(DAY, -LeadTime, SnapshotDate) AS LookbackDate
            , PartNum
            , OrderQty
        FROM #InputData
        ) subq
        --2.Join the data set onto itself, where the SnapshotDate is within the date range (LookbackDate, SnapshotDate). Also make sure PartNum is the same...
        --I've chosen not to be inclusive on both ends (like a BETWEEN), as it didn't feel right. But you can easily change this if you wish.
        ON inp.SnapshotDate > subq.LookbackDate AND inp.SnapshotDate <= subq.SnapshotDate
            AND inp.PartNum = subq.PartNum
    GROUP BY subq.SnapshotDate
        , subq.LookbackDate
        , subq.PartNum
    ) subq2
    ON inp.SnapshotDate = subq2.SnapshotDate
        AND inp.PartNum = subq2.PartNum
ORDER BY inp.SnapshotDate ASC
    , inp.PartNum ASC;
```

Try it yourself on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AK9RkAHW). You are probably going to want to change the input data set. As it currently stands there is nothing 'interesting' going on. All your SnapshotDates (for the same PartNum) are about 30 days apart. However, your lead times are less than 30 days. Play around with the values and see if this answers your question.